# Display beamer with timer and notes

Tags: beamer, viewers

I manage to create a really nice beamer template and notes. I can create 2 pdfs: one with slides, one with notes.
Now, I just need a dual screen pdf viewer that displays the slides in one screen and the notes in other screen and a **timer**. I need it for **Mac**.

Before mark as duplicated, I show off the collection of answers:
http://impressive.sourceforge.net/
https://code.google.com/p/splitshow/
https://github.com/TrilbyWhite/Slider
http://pympress.org/
http://impressive.sourceforge.net/

Does anyone know a better option for Mac? I don't find any acceptable solution :(

Keynote is, until now, the only acceptable but requires to copy the comments...

Comment: I've used SplitShow, but didn't need a timer. Looks like Impressive has a timer using the `T` hotkey, and would show your notes separately as long as you format the frames correctly, and use its `--half-screen` option. This won't use two separate PDFs, but one PDF with the slides and notes pages interleaved.

Comment: `pdfpc` also seems very nice. I've opened up an issue on Homebrew's site to add it (for ease of install); we'll see how that goes. I'm personally excited to use it for my thesis defense.